# Spring MVC and minify-maven-plugin does not recognize the <id>

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a running project with Spring MVC.

I'm trying to use the [minify-maven-plugin](http://samaxes.github.io/minify-maven-plugin/index.html).

I did the download of his sample project and based on the configuration the project I did mine. My pom.xml looked like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MeuProjeto</groupId>
  <artifactId>MeuProjeto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>src</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceExcludes>
                    **/font-awesome.css,**/magnific-popup.css,**/util.js,**/vuid.min.js
                </warSourceExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
            <executions>
                <id>default-minify</id>
                <configuration>
                    <cssSourceFiles>
                        <cssSourceFile>font-awesome.css</cssSourceFile>
                        <cssSourceFile>magnific-popup.css</cssSourceFile>
                    </cssSourceFiles>
                    <jsSourceFiles>
                        <jsSourceFile>util.js</jsSourceFile>
                        <jsSourceFile>vuid.min.js</jsSourceFile>
                    </jsSourceFiles>
                    <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                    <closureCreateSourceMap>true</closureCreateSourceMap>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>minify</goal>
                </goals>
            </executions>
        </plugin>  


    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
                <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
    <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The problem is that it is accusing error in this line of pom.xml:

default-minify

Error:

```
Description Resource Path Location Type cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'id'. One of '{"http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0":execution}' is expected. pom.xml /MeuProjeto line 53 XML Problem
```

What am I missing? I can not understand his reason for not accepting that tag.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. my falt

I forget the `<execution>` tag.

```
<executions>
            <execution>
                <id>default-minify</id>
                <configuration>
```

Including tag it works.